# How to add MinIO to nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, minio

I have nginx and minio runninh in Docker, but after setting server and trying to connect to minio, I get "502 Bad Gateway". How to resolve it?

docker-compose:

```
  minio:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/minio
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: supersecret
      MINIO_SERVER_URL: http://s.localhost
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: http://s.localhost/console
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/apps/minio_data

  volumes:
    minio_data:
       driver: local
```

And nginx template

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream server {
        server server:${SERVER_EXTERNAL_PORT};
    }

    upstream client-doctor {
        server client-doctor:${CLIENT_DOCTOR_EXTERNAL_PORT};
    }

    upstream client-pwa {
        server client-pwa:${CLIENT_PWA_EXTERNAL_PORT};
    }

    upstream storage{
        least_conn;
        server localhost:9000;
    }

    upstream storage_console{
        least_conn;
        server localhost:9001;
    }

  server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://server;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://client-pwa;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }

  server{
  listen 80;
  server_name doctor.localhost;

  location / {
       proxy_pass http://client-doctor;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }

server{
        listen       80;
        listen  [::]:80;
        server_name s.localhost;

   # Allow special characters in headers
      ignore_invalid_headers off;
      # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
      # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # Disable buffering
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_request_buffering off;

location / {
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

         proxy_connect_timeout 300;
         # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Connection "";
         chunked_transfer_encoding off;

         proxy_pass http://storage; # This uses the upstream directive definition to load balance
      }

      location /console {
            rewrite ^/console/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            # This is necessary to pass the correct IP to be hashed
            real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

            proxy_connect_timeout 300;

            # To support websockets in MinIO versions released after January 2023
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            chunked_transfer_encoding off;

            proxy_pass https://storage_console; # This uses the upstream directive definition to load balance
         }
    }
}
```

If not to set MINIO_SERVER_URL and MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL, and try to get to MinIO throw localhost:9001, I get "502 Bad Gateway" when try to get like "s.localhost", but when I wrote "localhost:9000" I got into the console